# What is the correct SQL statement to get the Row Source for a table, based on another field?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I currently have a schema set up in the following manner:

[image]

The table tblCategoryRiskArea is set up as an intermediate table for the many-to-many relationship that can exist between Categories and RiskAreas.

Within the tblBase table, I would like to make it so that the RiskArea choices are dependant upon the Category choice.  MS Access allows you to set a Lookup for a field in a table based upon a Row Source SQL statement.  I am having trouble figuring out the correct SQL statement to define the Row Source for RiskArea dependant upon Category.  This:

```
    SELECT tblRiskAreas.RiskAreaID, tblRiskAreas.RiskArea
    FROM tblRiskAreas INNER JOIN 
    ((tblCategories INNER JOIN tblBase 
        ON tblCategories.CategoryId = tblBase.Category) 
           INNER JOIN tblCategoryRiskArea  
           ON tblCategories.CategoryId = tblCategoryRiskArea.Category)
           ON (tblRiskAreas.RiskAreaID = tblCategoryRiskArea.RiskArea) 
           AND (tblRiskAreas.RiskAreaID = tblBase.RiskArea)
    WHERE (((tblCategoryRiskArea.Category)=[tblBase]![Category]))
    ORDER BY tblRiskAreas.RiskAreaID;
```

is the best I've come up with so far, using MS Access' Query Builder, so all of the Inner Joins have been created just by my having defined the relationships between the tables and dragging them into the Query Builder.  This query returns nothing, however.

I suspect that it may have something to do with the circular nature of the relationships I set up?

Thank you.

Edited: tblRiskArea contains 4 RiskAreas, as follows:

```
Environmental
Health
Safety
Security
```

Each Category can fall into one or two of these RiskAreas, so the tblCategoryRiskArea creates the relationship bewtween them.

Comment: I'd remove Category and RiskArea from tblBase and replace them for CategoriRiskAreaID

Comment: what is the purpose of tblCategoryRiskArea?  tblBase already covers the many-to-many, so tblCategoryRiskArea is redundant.  Also it is poor practice to have a field called CategoryID on one table then just Category in another -- *especially* when you have a different field just called Category in the first table.  i.e. category != category

Comment: tblCategoryRiskArea defines the RiskAreas for different Categories.  For example, in tblCategories there is a Category named Asbestos.  The RiskAreas for Asbestos are Environmental and Health.  There is another category named Chemical Management whose RiskAreas are Environment and Safety.  All told there are 4 different RiskAreas and 18 categories, and each Category has one or two RiskAreas.  I created the intermediate table to define those relationships and to avoid repeating the RiskAreas in a table.

Comment: I will edit the above post to add clarity based on your question.

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein do you undestand my approach?

Comment: At first, I didn't, but I think I do now.  It makes sense.  I wonder, though, if it will cause me trouble in creating two different drop down boxes for Category and Risk Area?  I will have to give it some thought.

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein "I created the intermediate table to define those relationships"   aren't they already defined in tblBase?  if not, why not?  somewhere, you are defining the relationships twice.

Answer (score 0):

First remove Category and RiskArea from tblBase and replace them for CategoriRiskAreaID

You will show in your form 2 combos. First combo Catagory data source:

```
Select CategoryId,Category from tblCategories
```

Second combo Risk Areas data source:

```
Select a.CategoryRiskId, b.RiskArea 
from tblCategoryRiskArea a
inner join tblRiskArea b
where a.RiskAreaId=b.RiskAreaId
AND a.category = @ComboBoxCategorySelectedItem
```

Now you have the value to insert in tblBase, ComboBoxSelectedItem is tblCategoryRiskArea.CategoryRiskId